# Is it possible to record actual sound on the simulator using mic

Tags: ios, iphone, ios-simulator

Is it possible record the actual sound on the simulator using the mic.
I have created the recorder which record the sound in simulator but not recording the actual audio its just null(empty) audio.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

iOS Simulator does not support audio recording, you should use real device to test.

Here you can read about [Limitations of Testing in iOS Simulator](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/iOS_Simulator_Guide/TestingontheiOSSimulator/TestingontheiOSSimulator.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012848-CH4-SW1)

> Hardware Limitations While most of the functionality of iOS devices
> can be simulated in iOS Simulator, there are some hardware features
> that must be tested directly on a device. The hardware features that
> cannot be simulated are:
>
> Accelerometer
>
> Gyroscope
> Camera
> Proximity  Sensor
>
> **Microphone Input**

Comment: Oh what a drag, i really like if simulator do that. but anyways thanx for reply and link.+1

Comment: It works fine for me using AVAudioRecorder with earphones in the physical line-in port

Comment: It works for me on MacBook air. I am able to record sound using simulator.

Comment: It's WRONG, take a better look to the limitations specs: it's talking about the simulation of *real devices*. Simulation if, for example GPS, give a fix location. The Simulator does make sounds. Catching them is a bit more difficult, I use SoundFlower. Not immediate to configure but it works.

Comment: I've not managed this so far, I've also installed soundflower, but I get no sound when using `xcrun simctl` ??

Comment: iOS 13 with Xcode 11: I just pulled out all of my simulator specific code paths and compiler directives around my audio code and recording just works. Still throws exceptions, so it will pause if you have an "all exceptions" breakpoint set. But you can continue and recording will start. However, it's always a good idea to test on actual devices.

Answer (score 19):

The old answer for this question is now incorrect; the iOS Simulator now supports audio input/recording.

Pic below related: where you set your audio input device (defaults to your system default)

Also be warned, some online Apple dev docs still say audio input is unsupported by the simulator ("as of 8.2") even though it is with newer versions...

Edit: Screenshot from OS X 10.12 (Sierra), Xcode 9.1 (function is also available in later Xcode 8, > 8.2)

[image: Photo of Audio Input Selection Menu on Simulator]

Comment: Hmm really interesting, but I don't have this on my Simulator, can you tell me more with the sim/xcode version ? Some features (catching video via the ```xcrun simctl``` command line) require that you Mac runs the "Metal" API, is this about my issue ?

Comment: Added version info above, screenshot from OS X 10.12 (Sierra), Xcode 9.1 (function is also available in later Xcode 8, > 8.2). Metal is a graphics API so it is likely not the issue if you can't access your internal mic via simulator. What version OS X/ Xcode are you on?

Comment: Thanks; strangely my OS X is 10.13.1 (High Sierra) but my Xcode 8.2 (8C38), with nothing to update in the App Store application... perhaps I'm restricted to the french store ?

Comment: - I'd found this restriction : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41240133/ios-simulator-video-recording-with-xcrun-simct-give-error, "Video recording is only supported on Macs that support **Metal**", my iMac is not in the models that support Metal (https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT205073)

- as I mentioned supra, I use SoundFlower now, it works fine

Comment: @tontonCD can you advise me on your configuration, can you get audio to work with `xcrun simctl` ?

Comment: This is a feature of Xcode 9+ in combination with iOS 11+.

Comment: `AVCaptureSession` fails to initialize with this

Comment: I'm using Mac M1 && Xcode Version 12.5 (12E262), sound is not recorded on simulator, even try commad line still no sound, what a pity.