# iOS: Audio recording setup fails in simulator, but not on my device?

Tags: ios, iphone, audio, ios-simulator, audio-recording

I am recording audio in my app.
The app runs in my iPhone 5C with iOS 7 just fine, but it fails in the simulator (iPhone Retina 3,5-inch / 4-inch/ 4-inch 64 bit)

Here is the code to setup audio:

```
-(void)setupAudio{
    _audioMessageLabel.text = @"...Bereit für Aufnahme...";
    [_stopButton setEnabled:NO];
    [_playButton setEnabled:NO];

    // Set the audio file
    NSString *guid = [[NSUUID new] UUIDString];
    _dateiName = [NSString  stringWithFormat:@"audio-notiz-%@.m4a", guid];
    NSLog(@"dateiName: %@", _dateiName);
    NSArray  *pathComponents = [NSArray  arrayWithObjects:
                            [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject],
                            _dateiName,
                            nil];
    _outputFileURL = [NSURL  fileURLWithPathComponents:pathComponents];

    // Setup audio session
    AVAudioSession *session = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
    [session setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord error:nil];

    // Define the recorder setting
    NSMutableDictionary  *recordSetting = [[NSMutableDictionary  alloc] init];

    [recordSetting setValue:[NSNumber  numberWithInt:kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC] forKey:AVFormatIDKey];
    [recordSetting setValue:[NSNumber  numberWithFloat:44100.0] forKey:AVSampleRateKey];
    [recordSetting setValue:[NSNumber  numberWithInt: 2] forKey:AVNumberOfChannelsKey];

    // Initiate and prepare the recorder

    NSError *error = nil;

    recorder = [[AVAudioRecorder alloc] initWithURL:_outputFileURL settings:recordSetting error:&error];

    if (error)
    {
        NSLog(@"error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);

    } else {
        recorder.delegate = self;
        recorder.meteringEnabled = YES;
        [recorder prepareToRecord];
   }
}
```

It fails in the last line `[recorder prepareToRecord]` with (lldb) in the console

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue could be, that the ios simulator doesn't support microphone:

[Is it possible to record actual sound on the simulator using mic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20090128/is-it-possible-to-record-actual-sound-on-the-simulator-using-mic)

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/iOS_Simulator_Guide/TestingontheiOSSimulator/TestingontheiOSSimulator.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012848-CH4-SW1