# Screencast of iPhone Simulator in Xcode 9

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios-simulator

I did an animation app with video and music, displayed full screen. Is it possible to capture a screencast of a running app in the simulator with `Xcode 9`?

Update: Did a research. Metal was not found on my machine, which is required. Thx Evgeny

Comment: What did you find in a web search? Please [edit] your question and add what you found and why it didn't help.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be a programming question. You're basically asking for a screencast-making application, such as QuickTime Player or ScreenFlow (that's what I use for this). But that is outside the scope of Stack Overflow.

Comment: THX guys, you´re right!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no such `Xcode` feature.
But you can use `QuickTime Player` for Simulator screen capturing.
Another option is `xcrun` command line utility.

Comment: in terminal i tried this: xcrun simctl io booted recordVideo gtht.mp4. and got this error2018-09-15 13:02:05.963 simctl[1108:19015] Error loading /System/Library [...] Did find:
 /System/Library/Extensions/GeForceMTLDriverWeb.bundle/Contents/MacOS/GeForceMTLDriverWeb: code signature in (/System/Library/Extensions     [...] not valid for use in process using Library Validation: mapping process is a platform binary, but mapped file is not
Error: Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=22 "Invalid argument" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Video recording requires hardware Metal capability.}.

Comment: Check this post - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41240133/ios-simulator-video-recording-with-xcrun-simct-give-error

Comment: Looks like your Mac doesn't support Metal required for video recording.

Comment: will try different machine. THX!